# How to do a look behind in perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to do a look behind using regex.

What I have tried seems to work but nothing is being captured.

```
my $names="Frank_J_Smith_1980-01-05.doc";
if($names =~ /(?![0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/)
{
     print("$1");
}
```

I wrote a match statement using the same code and it matches.

```
 if($names =~ /.*_(?![0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/)
 {
   print("$1");
 }
```

I am expecting to see `Frank_J_Smtih` but I am getting nothing.  It does hit the if statement finds the date but the output is nothing.

Comment: It's an _assertion_, just to "look" (no capturing).  If you want to capture use a match.

Comment: Otherwise use a lookahead `if($names =~ /(.*)(?=_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you probably meant here is a lookahead not a lookbehind:

```
if($names =~ /(.*)(?=_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/)
{
     print("$1");
}
```

Expression inside `(?=...)` is a positive lookahead here which means there is an underscore followed by date string ahead of current position.

Also note that `(.*)` is a captured group that you need to use to be able to use `$1` later.

**Without capturing group**, you can use:

```
if($names =~ /.*(?=_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/)
{
     print("$&\n");
}
```

Where `$&` represents full matched string from regex.

---

Otherwise you can just use substitute:

```
$names =~ s/_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\..*//;
print("$names");
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use a negative lookahead.

```
if($name =~ /((?:(?!_\d).)*)/) {
    print $1
}
```

This expression will capture everything until an underscore followed by a digit is found.

The `(?! ...` is the negative lookahead.